# How to strip all HTML tags from a string in regex101 task 8?

Tags: html, regex

Here is [website](https://regex101.com/quiz/8)

I use `/<[^>]*?>/g` to match it. But result is `Your pattern is not working. I believe it's stripping more than it should when applied to the text before<br>after`.

What mean is it? I think `<br>` is tags as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the string you are trying to process with this regex. External links on their own are not enough, as they can break or change over time and make the question invalid and unhelpful to future users.

Comment: I also want know which string not work. But the website not tell me.

Comment: Then you need to narrow it down bit by bit until you find it. We can't help you fix a problem if we can't the problem :)

Comment: Thank your answer, I'm trying.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was a bug. But now your regex is causing another problem - "Test 12/15: Tags can sometimes span multiple lines. For that reason you should also remove `partial` tags, which may be missing either `<` or `>` if they occur at the start or end of the string, respectively. For example, `body>text</body`"

My solution was:`/<?[^<>]*>|<[^>]*/g`

[This repo](https://github.com/0/Freenode-regex-quiz/tree/master/tests) can also be helpful

Comment: Why are you so vaguely saying _another problem_ instead of clearly stating it?

Comment: Because this question is closely related to the conditions of the task. They issue regular expression adjustments in portions. So I can't be sure that after a conditional month, their order will not change. And the expression given by the author will not start to fail elsewhere.

Comment: I can't follow your line of thought. Exactly because the order of tests as well as the failure messages on that site can change, it would be valuable here to state the found problem(s).